# How to get the user name and surname from the cells that contains the user email (Google Apps)?

Tags: forms, google-forms

I collect answers from google forms only froom my own domain, i.e. the users has to be logged in. I coillect their username (xxxx.xxxx@mydomain.com)in a specified column. Which kind of formula can I use to get the user name and surname? It should be possible to do it. (All of the users has username are in the form name.surname@domain.com. Right now I use "text formula" that separates the name and surname. This is a bit problematic because then Swedish name  can contain the letters " å, ä and ö"

Comment: Wellcome to SO friend. I recommend you to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39437310/edit) your question and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Share your code so people can understand your problem.

Comment: Please give an example of when the text formula fails.  Is this in Apps Script code, or a spreadsheet formula?  If you are using Apps Script code, you can add the google-apps-script tag to your question.